# nVidia nvlddmkm.sys BSOD as well as chronic driver crashing

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I get the `nvlddmkm.sys` BSOD whenever I play any game, and sometimes even when I'm not doing anything GPU intensive.

It gets so bad that after that happens I often cannot reboot without rebooting into the BSOD and I end up having to take out my GPU.

I have tried changing it to `nvlddmkm.sys.old`
I have used DDU to completely erase the old drivers and reinstall new drivers.

I also often get the `kernel mode driver has stopped working and recovered successfully` error where it would flicker to a black screen before going back to normal without a BSOD, but it would usually lead to a BSOD.

Event Viewer raises this warning before the error: The description from source nvlddmkm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed or the installation is corrupt.

---

Specs:

Nvidia GTX 770

Corsair HX 750

AsRock Fatal1ty Z87

Intel i5

---

I don't have the actual dmp files since they produced a 0kb dump, and this is from an older one when it occurred before (this is a chronic issue):

http://www.mediafire.com/download/1rp6vt9j82yu1me/011615-17955-01.dmp

```
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`02e1e000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03063e90
Debug session time: Fri Jan 16 04:23:17.872 2015 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:01:56.871
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

VIDEO_TDR_TIMEOUT_DETECTED (117)
The display driver failed to respond in timely fashion.
(This code can never be used for real bugcheck).
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffa8006b352b0, Optional pointer to internal TDR recovery context (TDR_RECOVERY_CONTEXT).
Arg2: fffff88005bf5bfc, The pointer into responsible device driver module (e.g owner tag).
Arg3: 0000000000000000, The secondary driver specific bucketing key.
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Optional internal context dependent data.

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

FAULTING_IP: 
nvlddmkm+13ebfc
fffff880`05bf5bfc ??              ???

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  GRAPHICS_DRIVER_TDR_TIMEOUT

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_202b:  *** Unknown TAG in analysis list 202b


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x117

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`04c7a4f0 fffff880`065325f7 : fffffa80`06b352b0 fffff880`0657eec4 fffffa80`06b352b0 fffff880`06500843 : watchdog!WdDbgReportRecreate+0xa3
fffff880`04c7aa10 fffff880`065332bc : fffff8a0`0d40d390 fffff8a0`0d40d390 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`06b352b0 : dxgkrnl!TdrUpdateDbgReport+0xcb
fffff880`04c7aa60 fffff880`065076b3 : 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`0c4cd000 00000000`00000000 fffff880`0000002a : dxgkrnl!TdrCollectDbgInfoStage2+0x220
fffff880`04c7aa90 fffff880`06533e0f : fffffa80`0c300658 ffffffff`fffe7960 fffffa80`06b352b0 00000000`00000000 : dxgkrnl!DXGADAPTER::Reset+0xef
fffff880`04c7ab40 fffff880`05a37ec1 : fffffa80`0d79cd50 00000000`00000080 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0c300010 : dxgkrnl!TdrResetFromTimeout+0x23
fffff880`04c7abc0 fffff800`0313bcce : 00000000`fffffc32 fffffa80`0bedfb60 fffffa80`066769e0 fffffa80`0bedfb60 : dxgmms1!VidSchiWorkerThread+0x101
fffff880`04c7ac00 fffff800`02e8ffe6 : fffff800`03010e80 fffffa80`0bedfb60 fffff800`0301ecc0 fffff880`0161b384 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`04c7ac40 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`04c7b000 fffff880`04c75000 fffff880`087e1760 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  .bugcheck ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nvlddmkm+13ebfc
fffff880`05bf5bfc ??              ???

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+13ebfc

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  548be25d

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x117_IMAGE_nvlddmkm.sys

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x117_IMAGE_nvlddmkm.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: How long have you been facing this issue? Was the GPU working correctly before?

Comment: Around three months. The GPU was fine for a little more than half a year as well @gronostaj

Comment: You have all windows updates installed?  If you don't install the Nvidia drivers does this happen?  Does this happen if you use Autoruns to load the very mininium then run an application of your choice?

Comment: Yes. If I don't have the drivers installed then it goes back to integrated graphics. I can boot in safe mode sometimes, but I've had a few times when my computer crashes with the issue right before login. @Ramhound

Comment: You can only boot into safe mode sometimes?  If you are crashing in safe mode then its not caused by the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: try to increase the TdrDelay value: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2665946

Comment: @magicandre1981 will this prevent the bsod as well?

Comment: it gives the GPU more time to recover before Windows bugchecks to system.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have increased the TdrDelay to 8, and the issue still happens

Comment: try this "Prefer Max performance" setting change: http://itproguru.com/expert/2013/04/nvidia-display-driver-stopped-responding-and-has-recovered-heres-a-simple-fix-thats-worked-for-many/#sthash.xEYb5x8D.dpuf

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's already been done ages ago

Comment: @magicandre1981 in fact now I think the problem is more frequent. I also checked on the temperature of my gpu when this was happening and it was at a pretty low 45C

Comment: ask a friend to test your GPU. If he also gets the crashes, the card is faulty.

Comment: @magicandre1981 You were correct, GPU was faulty and I'm attempting to get an RMA on it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive testing via FurMark, as well as having someone else use the GPU, it has been determined that the GPU was faulty and needed to be replaced.

Comment: ok, report back if the replacement GPU works fine.